# Are custom named functions acceptable notation?

Tags: functions, notation

A custom name being, for example, my function name (MFN):

$MFN(x) := ax + b$

As contrasted with:

$\delta(x) := ax + b$

Questions:

1. Is it permissible to name the function $MFN$ above? Or is this restricted to very well known functions, such as $sgn(x)$?
2. Can you refer me to a source for the use of word abbreviations as names of functions?
3. Is lower-case preferred to upper-case? What circumstances dictate upper-case function names (or letters)?

Comment: $\operatorname{MFN}$ is just as good as name for a function as $f$, but the convention is to use non-italics for multi-letter names of functions (`\operatorname{}`). I don't have a source, which is why this is a comment.

Comment: Yes: it's down to you (and anybody reviewing your work). But names with more than one letter  don't typeset very nicely in $\LaTeX$ if you don't wrap them in \mathsf{} or \mathrm{} or \operatorname{} giving $\mathsf{FUNCTION}$ or $\mathrm{FUNCTION}$ or $\operatorname{FUNCTION}$ rather than $FUNCTION$. (I like the sans serif, personally and you can use lower case or upper case or a mixture.)

Comment: you could give a specific function through out a paper a longer name. don't give a generic function (think as kind of variable) a long name.

Comment: @RobArthan, `\operatorname` does more than just change the font;  you should write something like `\operatorname{\mathsf{FUNCTION}}` to get correct spacing and such things. (If you want to change the font of all operator names, see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43131/the-font-of-operator-names))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The knee-jerk answer is that you can use any notation as long as you define it before you use it.

But mathematicians generally prefer single-letter function names, which is part of the reason why certain letters of the Greek alphabet have more than one function attached to them (e.g., Carmichael's and Liouville's $\lambda(n)$).

I thought I had seen an example of a function name with two capital letters on Mathworld but now I can't find it. The problem with using two or three lowercase letters is that it might look like a standard function, like $\log x$ or $\sin y$.

From what I've seen over the years, the preference for custom function symbols goes something like this:

- a single lowercase Latin letter
- a single Greek letter
- two uppercase Latin letters
- three uppercase Latin letters
- two or three lowercase Latin letters

If you choose to use more than one Latin letter, it's best not to italicize them as it looks like a title.